# many to many retreiving book & author name error laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

Unable to display all books name and author name as list. Getting error. If I return the books and authors variables in controller (index method) I get the data as array. But unable to access them in view. Also as mentioned in commented code (in Book Controller) below, code from laravel documentation shows error.

**Book Model**

```
class Book extends Model
{
 protected $guarded = [];

 public function authors(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Author')->withTimestamps();
 }
}
```

**Author Model**

```
class Author extends Model
{
 public $guarded = [];

 public function books(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Book')->withTimestamps();
 }
}
```

**Book Controller**

```
 public function index()
{
    $query = Book::with('authors')->get();
    Pls Read the commented lines below -
    //foreach ($query as $book) {
    //return $book->authors->author_name;  //Error: Property [author_name] does not exist on this collection instance.
    //}
    // (above code is given in laravel documentation but shows error : why?) 
    foreach($query as $b){
     $books[] = $b->book_name; 
     $authors[] = $b->authors->first()->author_name; 
    }
    return view('books.index', compact('books','authors'));
}

public function create()
{
    return view('books.create');
}

public function store(validateAuthorBook $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();
    if($validated){
        $book = new Book();
        $book->book_name = $request->book_name;
        $book->save();

        $author = new Author();
        $author->author_name = $request->author_name;
        $author->save();

        $book->authors()->attach($author);
    }

    return back()->with('status', 'Insert Successful!');
}
```

**View (index.blade.php)**

```
  @foreach($books as $b)
    <tr>
        <th>{{$loop->iteration}}</th>
        <td>{{$b->book_name}}</td>
        //<td>how to get author name</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
```

**error**

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'book_name' of non-object (View: 
D:\ProgrammingSSD\laragon\www\ulclibrary\resources\views\books\index.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error because you are making `$book` a string in array (`$books[] = $b->book_name;`). You shouldn't do anything with `$books` collection in controller, and could send it directly to view.

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $books = Book::with('authors')->get();
    return view('books.index', compact('books'));
}
```

**View (one line, split authors with comma):**

```
@foreach($books as $book)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
        <td>{{ $book->book_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $book->authors->pluck('author_name')->implode(', ') }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**View (loop, split authors with new line):**

```
@foreach($books as $book)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
        <td>{{ $book->book_name }}</td>
        <td>
            @foreach($book->authors as $author)
                {{ $author->author_name }}<br/>
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you. The 1st view method works, but the 2nd one shows error - Property [authors] does not exist on this collection instance.